# How to invoke function pointer, through another pointer type?

Tags: c++

Question might be a bit confusing; here's the problem:

I have this:

```
class FunctionContainer
{
   void* functionPointer;
}

void Test()
{
    cout << 'a';
}

int main()
{
    FunctionContainer* f = new FunctionContainer();
    f->functionPointer = &Test;
    f->functionPointer;
}
```

My problem here is that I can't invoke the function like this, it just skips the line. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `f->functionPointer;` is not an attempt at calling the function (that would involve parenthesis). But it's also not a function pointer, it's a pointer to `void`

Comment: How can I create the function pointer then?

Comment: There are no function pointers in this code.

Comment: `void (*functioPointer)();` in this case. The return type and the parameters have to be incorporated into the type.

Comment: and `f->functionPointer();` to call the function

Comment: To address your question's title: Invoking a function pointer through the wrong pointer type is instant undefined behavior.  https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#6

Comment: Using [C++ lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and [`std::function`-s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) is often a better idea. See also [ASMJIT](https://asmjit.com/) and on POSIX [dlopen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) with [dlsym](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html)

Comment: Standard-conforming code isn't allowed to store the address of a function in a `void*`. A pointer-to-function isn't necessarily the same size as a pointer-to-data.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is this:

```
class FunctionContainer
{
public:
   void (*functionPointer)(void);
}

void Test()
{
    cout << 'a';
}

int main()
{
    FunctionContainer* f = new FunctionContainer();
    f->functionPointer = &Test;
    f->functionPointer();
}
```

Where

```
returnType (*variableName)(argumentType1, argumentType2, argumentType3...);
```

And (in this example)

```
returnType name = f->variableName(argument1, argument2, argument3...);
```